# How to stop cdh's STREAMSETS parcel installing with activing stage

Tags: cloudera-cdh, parcel, streamsets

cm api: *cluster:7180/ap1/v14/clusters/cluster/parcels/products/STREAMSETS_DATACOLLECTOR/versions/3.2.0.0*

reword：

```
{
  "product" : "STREAMSETS_DATACOLLECTOR",
  "versions" : "3.2.0.0",
  "stage" : "ACTIVATING",
  "state" : {
     "progress" : 0,
     "totalProgress" : 100,
     "count" : 0,
     "totalCouny" : 3
  },
  "clusterRef" : {
      "clusterName" : "cluster"
  }
}
```

now It's always activing, I cound't stop it!!!

like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arUV9.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCYlc.jpg)

please help me!!

ps: use api: *cluster:7180/ap1/v14/clusters/cluster/parcels/products/STREAMSETS_DATACOLLECTOR/versions/3.2.0.0/commands/deactive* can not stop it;

**now has solved. use curl -u username:password -X POST "...cm api"**

Comment: Please add more description. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Can you add the solution as an answer, so that it's clear that it's been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use command in linux to execute the api：

> curl -u username:password -X POST
>   "http://ip:7180/ap1/v14/clusters/cluster/parcels/products/STREAMSETS_DATACOLLECTOR/versions/3.2.0.0"

to end activing statge .

do not be with web page to execute apis, its not to take effect